# GAE pubsub client can not publish

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I followed with the GAE pub-sub client sample code to implement publish message. It worked for 1 day.

But it stop publishing any message today. I use pub/sub client code similar with example code in https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher.

If I publish message through https://console.cloud.google.com on the topic, my client can receive the message without any problem.

Are there any issue with the publish code or I need ?

```
public static void publish(String message) throws Exception {
TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);


Publisher publisher = null;
List<ApiFuture<String>> messageIdFutures = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();
    ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
    PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = 
    PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build();
    ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
    messageIdFutures.add(messageIdFuture);
}finally {
    List<String> messageIds = ApiFutures.allAsList(messageIdFutures).get();
    for (String messageId : messageIds) {
        System.out.println("published with message ID: " + messageId);

    }
    if (publisher != null) {
        // When finished with the publisher, shutdown to free up resources.
        publisher.shutdown();
    }
```

}

Comment: Your issue might be related to this [incident](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/18003), especially since it worked but then it stopped publishing and it is a GAE client (GAE being affected by the incident). Retry, as the incident is resolved. Works now?

Comment: Thanks. I found the reason that I should use PUBSUB old version.